# sudo without prompt in CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I have a java application connect to a remote CentOS using ssh connection.

There's a shell script, in order to execute it, I need to input the password.

```
[user@**** ~]$ sudo ***
Password:
```

My question is how to execute the script without prompt .(I can't modify `/etc/sudoers`  and I also don't want to use outputStream to send the password.)

Comment: Let's see, you don't want to modify `sudoers` and don't want to give the password to `sudo`... I.e. you want to bypass security. Not going to happen.

Comment: This may work; `echo password| sudo -S ***`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and much more secure way is to sudo visudo and attach "NOPASSWD:" to get sudo not require a password.

The way in the middle is using the sudo -S parameter, that expect the password coming from standard input instead that from the terminal device.

The worst and less secure way is to pass a clear text password that one could catch even via ps -ef command using "expect" utility (install it, then "man expect")

Comment: So this is what I want: `echo password| sudo -S ***`